# Creating a rotated geospatial PDF

Tags: pdf, geospatial, measurement

I am creating hiking/walking maps in PDF. As an extra feature, I add a viewport to the PDF with a geospatial measurement dictionary. This is to relate positions on the page to actual geographic coordinates.

I follow the Adobe documentation in https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf. In a simple scenario this works fine: Acrobat, with the Geospatial Location Tool enabled, shows the correct coordinates of the mouse position.

For some reasons that are related to actually printing the PDFs, I want to rotate the map on the page. From my understanding of the PDF 7 specification document, (Section 8.8) all that I have to do is to provide a rotated main diagonal in the BBox of the viewport dictionary of my map. And that is what I do. (Apart from rotating the image)

In the rotated version of the map, Acrobat recognizes the main diagonal of the rectangle correctly. However for the other two corners the relation between the geographical (lat/lon) and the geometric (x,y) coordinates is swapped.

Does anyone have a clue about what is wrong with my PDF file? An example of an upright one is https://mdedoes.home.xs4all.nl/maarssen-25000.pdf and a rotated one is https://mdedoes.home.xs4all.nl/maarssen-25000-r.pdf .

For completeness sake, I include a listing of the viewport distionary of the page. (Extracted from the actual file with PDFBox)

```
 VP[0].Name=n:Maarssen
 VP[0].BBox[0]=f:42.5197
 VP[0].BBox[1]=f:552.7559
 VP[0].BBox[2]=f:325.98428
 VP[0].BBox[3]=f:42.5197
 VP[0].Measure:o.Bounds[0]=f:0.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.Bounds[1]=f:0.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.Bounds[2]=f:0.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.Bounds[3]=f:1.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.Bounds[4]=f:1.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.Bounds[5]=f:1.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.Bounds[6]=f:1.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.Bounds[7]=f:0.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.GCS:o.Type=n:GEOGCS
 VP[0].Measure:o.GCS:o.EPSG=i:4289
 VP[0].Measure:o.GCS:o.WKT=s:GEOGCS["Amersfoort", Etc
 VP[0].Measure:o.DCS:o.Type=n:PROJCS
 VP[0].Measure:o.DCS:o.EPSG=i:28992
 VP[0].Measure:o.DCS:o.WKT=s:PROJCS["Amersfoort / RD New", Etc
 VP[0].Measure:o.GPTS[0]=f:52.151005
 VP[0].Measure:o.GPTS[1]=f:4.9930854
 VP[0].Measure:o.GPTS[2]=f:52.173477
 VP[0].Measure:o.GPTS[3]=f:4.9928865
 VP[0].Measure:o.GPTS[4]=f:52.17368
 VP[0].Measure:o.GPTS[5]=f:5.0586777
 VP[0].Measure:o.GPTS[6]=f:52.151207
 VP[0].Measure:o.GPTS[7]=f:5.058843
 VP[0].Measure:o.LPTS[0]=f:0.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.LPTS[1]=f:0.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.LPTS[2]=f:0.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.LPTS[3]=f:1.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.LPTS[4]=f:1.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.LPTS[5]=f:1.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.LPTS[6]=f:1.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.LPTS[7]=f:0.0
 VP[0].Measure:o.PDU[0]=s:M
 VP[0].Measure:o.PDU[1]=s:SQM
 VP[0].Measure:o.PDU[2]=s:DEG
 VP[0].Measure:o.Subtype=n:GEO
 VP[0].Measure:o.Type=n:Viewport
```

Comment: I am running in to an issue where pdfs made with gdal are displaying upside down. Did you ever figure this out? Is there anyway you could fix the links above? I would like to try them .

Answer (score 1):

The LPTS array maps the geo points in GPTS to the corners of your viewport relative to the coordinate system defined by BBox.

Use this value for LPTS and the lat/long will be handled correctly: [0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0]

The top left corner is (0,0) the bottom right is (1,1). Your GPTS points are given in the order (top,left), (top,right), (bottom,right), (bottom,left) so the LPTS array is (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1).

Comment: you seem to know PDFs well (not least with your username). This answer so far helped me write a PDF parser. Do you know if tokens in the streams (Trailer > Root > Pages > Kids > [kidIndex] > Contents > [stream or streams] > [stream]) are always delimited with byte 10? I notice some seem to be delimited with 10 13, while others with 10 only. Not sure if other bytes can be used and not sure where to find that information either (I didn't find any official documentation).

Comment: Nvm, I found the information I was looking for in section 3.1 of this official doc: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.7old.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The partial answer above (It works for the example) helped me to phrase a general solution:

With GPTS on the corners of the map rectangle in clockwise order, the order of the LPTS depends on the angle of the rotation. For rotations of an odd multiple of 90 degrees LPTS are in counter-clockwise order. For even multiples, LPTS are in clockwise order.

Possibly, a code fragment is easiest to understand:

```
// Emit GPTS
private static COSArray gpts( GeospatialPdfViewport mapViewport ) {

    Coordinate[] coordinates= new Coordinate[] {
            mapViewport.getGeographicLowerLeft(),
            mapViewport.getGeographicUpperLeft(),
            mapViewport.getGeographicUpperRight(),
            mapViewport.getGeographicLowerRight(),
    };

    COSArray pts= new COSArray();

    for ( Coordinate c: coordinates ) {
        // Lat(y)-Lon(x) rather than Lon-Lat
        pts.add( new COSFloat( (float)c.y ) );
        pts.add( new COSFloat( (float)c.x ) );
    }

    return pts;
}

/**
 * @param odd True for 90 or 270 degrees; False for 0 or 180 degrees
 * @return an LPTS array. The contents depend on the angle of rotation of the viewport
 */
private static COSArray lpts( boolean odd ) {

    if  ( odd ) {
        return toCOSArray( new Coordinate[] {
                new Coordinate( 0, 0 ),
                new Coordinate( 1, 0 ),
                new Coordinate( 1, 1 ),
                new Coordinate( 0, 1 ),             
        } );
    } else {
        return toCOSArray( new Coordinate[] {
                new Coordinate( 0, 0 ),
                new Coordinate( 0, 1 ),             
                new Coordinate( 1, 1 ),
                new Coordinate( 1, 0 ),             
        } );
    }
}

// Emit Bounds
private static COSArray bounds() {
    return toCOSArray( new Coordinate[] {
            new Coordinate( 0, 0 ),
            new Coordinate( 0, 1 ),
            new Coordinate( 1, 1 ),
            new Coordinate( 1, 0 ) } );
}
```